# BottomSheetView (@gorhom/bottom-sheet) in React Native shrinks by half height when BottomSheetTextInput is active

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, bottom-sheet

I'm using @gorhom/bottom-sheet library for React Native (Typescript) project and inside BottomSheetView, I have BottomSheetTextInput component. When BottomSheetTextInput is pressed my BottomSheet scales to 100% height of screen and BottomSheetView shrinks to half size and stays on top.

[image]

[image]

On the first picture BottomSheetTextInput is not being pressed and BottomSheet is at 80% value. On the next picture BottomSheetTextInput is pressed and content inside colapses to top

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve it. If anyone is facing the same issuse, this worked for me:

```
keyboardBehavior='interactive'
//@ts-ignore
keyboardBlurBehavior='restore'
android_keyboardInputMode='adjustResize'
```

Comment: I have exact same issue on Android, but can fix it like this. I need the keyboardBehavior='extend' otherwise the sheet is not opening too much. On iOS it works fine (as always) Any other suggestions to get rid of that strange empty space above the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix this like:

```
 <BottomSheet
      index={1}
      android_keyboardInputMode="adjustResize"
      ref={bottomSheetRef}
      snapPoints={['15%', '55%', '90%']}
      keyboardBehavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'extend' : 'interactive'}
      keyboardBlurBehavior="restore"
      enableContentPanningGesture={false}
      onChange={handleSheetChanges}
    >
```

and a when keyboard is shown on Android I 'extend' manually by going to snapToIndex(2)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // only needed for Android because
    // keyboardBehavior="extend" is not working properly
    // on Android, it leaves a gap between the keyboard and the bottom sheet
    // when the keyboard is visible
    const showSubscription = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', () => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        bottomSheetRef.current?.snapToIndex(2);
      }
    });
    return () => {
      showSubscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: made an issue for this https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet/issues/1581